# How to parse an Object

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a Job object that contains JobTypeId, JobClassId,GeoAreaId. I can successfully send back one id to the apiController but when i try to parse all 3 of them I get a error:

> Unexpected token o at Object.parse (native)

Angular Controller

```
 $scope.updateJob = function (job) {
    console.log($scope.currentItem);
    var jt = JSON.parse($scope.currentItem.JobType)
    var jc = JSON.parse($scope.currentItem.JobClass)
    var ga = JSON.parse($scope.currentItem.GeoArea)
    job.JobTypeId = jt.JobTypeId;
    job.JobClassId = jc.JobClassId;
    job.GeoAreaId = ga.GeoAreaId;
    jobFactory.updateJob(job).success(successCallback)
        .error(errorCallback);
    console.log(job); 
};
var successCallback = function (data, status, headers, config) {
    notificationFactory.success();
};
var errorCallback = function (job, status, headers, config) {
    notificationFactory.error(job.ExceptionMessage);
};
```

View

```
 <select ng-controller="JobMiscCtrl" style="width:148px" ng-model="currentItem.JobType">
   <option ng-repeat="job in jobTypeArray" title="{{job.JobTypeName}}" ng-selected=" {{job.JobTypeId == currentItem.JobTypeId}}" value="{{job}}">
     {{job.JobTypeName}}
   </option>
 </select>
 <select ng-controller="JobMiscCtrl" style="width:148px" ng-model="currentItem.JobClass">
    <option ng-repeat="job in jobClassArray" title="{{job.JobClassName}}" ng-selected="{{job.JobClassId == currentItem.JobClassId}}" value="{{job}}">
    {{job.JobClassName}}
    </option>
 </select>
 <select ng-controller="JobMiscCtrl" style="width:148px" ng-model="currentItem.GeoArea">
   <option ng-repeat="job in geoAreaArray" title="{{job.GeoAreaName}}" ng-selected="{{job.GeoAreaId == currentItem.GeoAreaId}}" value="{{job}}">
       {{job.GeoAreaName}}
   </option>
 </select>

 <input ng-controller="JobCtrl" style="margin-right: 20px; width: 70px; margin-top: 25px" type="submit" ng-click="updateJob(currentItem)" value="Submit" />
```

Updated
I moved everything into 1 controller. The view is returning a string. the apiController is expecting the JobTypeId only. So that is why I am trying to parse the Id properties from the string. this is what i am looking at

```
{{currentItem.GeoArea.GeoAreaId}}
   <label style="margin-left:57px">Geo&nbsp;Area:</label>
   <select style="width:148px" ng-model="currentItem.GeoArea.GeoAreaId">
    <option ng-repeat="job in geoAreaArray" title="{{job.GeoAreaName}}" ng-selected="{{job.GeoAreaId == currentItem.GeoAreaId}}" value="{{job}}">
     {{job.GeoAreaName}}
    </option>
   </select>
```

when I select a new GeoArea, you see what shows up in the currentItem.GeoArea.GeoAreaId
[image: pic]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to specifically call JSON.Parse on the object. Its already in the format you need. You can just do this.

```
$scope.updateJob = function (job) {
    console.log($scope.currentItem);

    var jt = $scope.currentItem.JobType;
    var jc = $scope.currentItem.JobClass;
    var ga = $scope.currentItem.GeoArea;

    job.JobTypeId = jt.JobTypeId;
    job.JobClassId = jc.JobClassId;
    job.GeoAreaId = ga.GeoAreaId;
    jobFactory.updateJob(job).success(successCallback)
        .error(errorCallback);
    console.log(job); 
};
```

Or even shorter

```
$scope.updateJob = function (job) {
    console.log($scope.currentItem);
    job.JobTypeId = $scope.currentItem.JobType.JobTypeId;
    job.JobClassId = $scope.currentItem.JobClass.JobClassId;
    job.GeoAreaId = $scope.currentItem.GeoArea.GeoAreaId;
    jobFactory.updateJob(job).success(successCallback)
        .error(errorCallback);
    console.log(job); 
};
```

Update your UI to make it simpler

```
<div ng-controller="JobMiscCtrl">        
   <select ng-model="currentItem.JobType" ng-options="job.JobTypeName for job in jobTypeArray"></select>
   <br/>
   <select ng-model="currentItem.JobClass" ng-options="job.JobClassName for job in jobClassArray"></select>
   <br/>
   <select ng-model="currentItem.GeoArea" ng-options="job.GeoAreaName for job in geoAreaArray"></select>
   <input style="margin-right: 20px; width: 70px; margin-top: 25px" type="submit" ng-click="updateJob(currentItem)" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

Comment: actually i clicked to soon. it is sending back null values to the apiController

Comment: That is a different issue. Firstly, try using simpler select syntax with Angular. Check this example. http://plnkr.co/edit/U4bAItk2KTh41ZIOvaap?p=preview Then see what you get.

Comment: dont quite follow you on using simpler syntax?

Comment: i see what you are saying. problem is I need to keep the ng-repeat and the other code in the view as is. Is there anything i can do with the Javascript?

Comment: If you are getting null values to the controller, its generally a problem with the bindings (in UI) not javascript. Atleast try to use the same controller for all the elements by creating an outer div. That way you can leave your ng-repeat as is. Otherwise, everytime you set the ng-controller directive, it will be a new object.

Comment: I see...change this value="{{job}}" to value="{{job.GeoAreaId}}" in this line <option ng-repeat="job in geoAreaArray" title="{{job.GeoAreaName}}" ng-selected="{{job.GeoAreaId == currentItem.GeoAreaId}}" value="{{job}}">